# Gmail API, Reply to thread not working / forwarding

Tags: ios, swift, api, email, gmail-api

I'm using the google gmail api in swift. All is working well, it's compiling etc.

I'm now trying forward an email, the only way I see this possible so far is by using a thread id.

So I'm using the API tester found here to send tests. Will will focus on this. It can be found here[1](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)

So I've input this, the "raw" is Base64 URL encoded string.

> {
>     "raw": "VG86ICBlbWFpbFRvU2VuZFRvQGdtYWlsLmNvbSAKU3ViamVjdDogIFRoZSBzdWJqZWN0IHRlc3QKSW4tUmVwbHktVG86ICBteUVtYWlsQGdtYWlsLmNvbQpUaHJlYWRJZDogIDE1YjkwYWU2MzczNDQ0MTIKClNvbWUgQ29vbCB0aGluZyBpIHdhbnQgdG8gcmVwbHkgdG8geW91ciBjb252by4u",
>     "threadId": "15b90ae637344412"
>   }

The "raw" in plain text is

To:  emailToSendTo@gmail.com 
Subject:  The subject test
In-Reply-To:  myEmail@gmail.com
ThreadId:  15b90ae637344412

Some Cool thing i want to reply to your convo..

when I execute it I get this back

> {
>    "id": "15b944f6540396df",
>    "threadId": "15b90ae637344412",
>    "labelIds": [
>     "SENT"
>    ]
>   }

But when I check both email account, from and to. None of them say the previous messages but are in the same "thread" or convo.

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated I've spent all day on this issue and half of yesterday and did TONS of research on it.

as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send?authuser=1) I should I'm adding the threaded and In-Reply-To in the right way I believe

The ID of the thread the message belongs to. To add a message or draft to a thread, the following criteria must be met:
The requested threadId must be specified on the Message or Draft.Message you supply with your request.
The References and In-Reply-To headers must be set in compliance with the RFC 2822 standard.
The Subject headers must match.

Comment: Note: I have only gotten this to work once! 
So I know it can work but the conversion got messed up and was unable to get what was In the raw at the time so I'm trying to figure out what needs to be in the raw in order for it to show the previous email's text within mine.

Comment: You may want to check these references - [Gmail API In-Reply-To not working](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33177306/5995040) and [How to have forward messages appear in the same thread with Gmail API](http://www.developersite.org/103-63445-python). These docs provide clarification how email threading work in Gmail. Try following this, first, subject must be similar. Second, sender must be a part of the thread OR in-reply-to must be used. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Mr.Rebot, I've decide to put the project aside for a few days and come back to it fresh. It may have been an issue server side. Will check these out more in detail, flicking through them I have seen these before. 

Will go back to this project soon again an try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gmail API In-Reply-To not working(Google not handling on one side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171769/gmail-api-in-reply-to-not-workinggoogle-not-handling-on-one-side)